# Fetch data from database according to the permissions

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization, system-design

I'm developing an application in which I need to develop role based access control. 
I've tried looking for other answers but those provides some different solution. Roles are dynamic, but permission are static as of now according to the modules we have in our application.

Here is my scenario.

I have staff and physician, staff are connected to physician. 
So permissions are `"View Physician", "Edit Physician", "View Appointment", "Edit Appointment"`, etc.

A staff can be a global user also and a local user also. So suppose if a staff is a global user, he has permissions for every physician.
If a staff is local user, he has permission to the specific phyiscian.

Now when a staff goes to appointment listing, api should return the data according to his permission, he should be able to see the list of appointment for only those physicians who has given him the permission "View Appointment">

Using `hasRole` and `hasAuthority`, I can restrict the complete API, but I need to fetch data from database based on permission. 
Hardcoding the permission in the JPA query for each db hit will be too much.

So I'm looking for some suggestions and help on the architecture or some desgin pattern for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is really broad but I try to answer that...

For those kind of situation spring security is the best way you may control the access of any API as per the role defined for the user

**configure** method of the [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.htmlhttps://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) class to configure the user with their specific roles and map the URL patterns as per the roles

**Remember WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class** has three versions of the **configure** method but for this scenario you only need two versions from them one for mapping the user i.e **configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)** with their specific roles and one for mapping the url patterns with their specific roles i.e **configure(HttpSecurity http)**

So by mapping the urls with specific roles you may easily control the API call  as per the user roles so no hardcode for the roles are required for the JPA queries

I share one example how you can map the url as per the roles

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http){
   http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/")
            .hasRole("Physician")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
```

**Note** you may use any other method for login as well

I hope this will help and motivate you to explore the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirements of difference query use-cases , I would use different strategies accordingly:

1. For the use-case that returns a single record (e.g find a record by ID) , the SQL query should not aware the user permission. Do application level security checking using [`@PostAuthorize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize) after getting the data from the database.
2. For the use-case that returns a list of records which allow user to configure the things like offset or limit (i.e pagination use-case) , the SQL query is aware of the user permission which means we need to add the necessary where clauses to the SQL query based on the user permission.

   The main reason for this is basically for the performance when the dataset is large and the difficulties if it is done in the application side using `@PostFilter`.

   For example , think about the case that if you need to get 5200th to 5400th records that  an user is permitted to view but you are not allow to add any where clause based on user permission to the SQL query , how would you tackle this problem if all the security checking is done in the application side ? I can only imagine the codes will be very messy and not efficient even I implement it correctly ....
3. For the use-case that returns a list of records but the user cannot configure the things like offset or limit , I would use the strategy same as (1) but use [`@PostFitler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#filtering-using-prefilter-and-postfilter) this time.

So unless there are special reasons such as (2) , the overall aim is to treat the security logic as a cross-cutting concerns as much as possible such that the core domain logic codes should not aware of its existence .The security codes should be centralised in one single place/package/modules etc but not scattered all over the codes. This basically means that we use the AOP technique provided by the spring security to execute some security checking codes on the returned objects after the query method finish execution.

Comment: but in this approach. suppose there is appointment listing page, I have local permission of 2 physicians and not have permission for other physicians. so when i open appointment listing, api should return data for only those 2 physicians.

Comment: i have no ideas what is your query use-case requirements ... As I ready mentioned if it is a pagination query which user needs to specify offset /limit kind of things in request , use strategy 2 and dynamic construct the SQL with the correct where clause to get the correct data that are supposed to be viewable to user.